# Salary adjusted after not moving to the city

Tags: salary

I work in [FAANG](https://www.businessinsider.com/personal-finance/what-is-faang?op=1&r=US&IR=T) and I was hired 2 years ago. The plan was I would move to Seattle from the Midwest and I initially wanted to move there but no one came to the office so I didn't move. I even visited the office a few times and it was empty. Even my coworker who has been working for the company for some time works from home all the time. Fast forward to two days ago when I got an email from HR saying I didn't move to Seattle and my salary is due to be adjusted. My manager said because I didn't move, my salary needs to reflect the city I currently live in and if I move to Seattle, my salary will go back to what it was.

My salary went from ~$150k to $115k. It's very depressing because I feel like I am not being valued, but my manager and my teammates have been happy with my work. I even got a salary increase a few months ago.

My question is this normal or even allowed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141987/discussion-on-question-by-node-js-salary-adjusted-after-not-moving-to-the-city).

Comment: What did your contract say? Did your contract say moving to 150k salary contingent on moving to Seattle? Or did it say moving to Seattle *and* 150k salary without explicitly linking the two? Or did it say 150k salary and the moving to Seattle was just in talks and not in the actual contract? Because there's a difference between being legal and accurate to the letter versus legal by omission (i.e. in bad faith).

Answer (score 82):

> My question is this normal or even allowed?

Salary adjustments based on cost of living are very common. Otherwise you would not find people to work in many areas and grossly overpay others.

The "plan" was that you earn 150K *in Seattle*. It did not go according to plan. You did *not* move to Seattle. Given that Washington is an "at will" state, if you did not have a contract saying otherwise, that could be a reason to fire you. Where you live inside the US is not a protected class (unless it hints at other protected classes, I'm sure it would be different if they fired everyone living in an Indian reservation). Given that your employer still upholds the option to follow the original plan and is still willing to pay you what was agreed on if you do what was agreed on, I can see no discrimination of any kind.

Yes, this is demotivating, to see how you make a lot less on paper now, that your salary has adjusted to your new plan. But in fact, you simply made too much all the years and you got away with it. They don't want it back. Not so bad.

I suggest you actually calculate, how much money you can save each month after you have paid *all* the bills. I would not be surprised if you ended up with a net positive for not moving. If you need motivation, look at the amount of money you save right now versus the amount you would be able to save in Seattle.

It still is your decision, do you want that salary? Would you get more money with the original plan? It is available under the same conditions it was when you took the job.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that COLA salary adjustments *of that magnitude* are common. Rule of thumb I usually hear tossed around is 30%~35% diff from Manhattan/Bay Area to Podunk. Seattle is not as expensive, but they're also not cutting as much.

Comment: @JaredSmith The US Government locality pay adjustment is 44.15% from minimum to San Francisco. Seattle is 29.57%, New York City gets 36.16%.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to actually calculate how much you're saving. Cost of living adjustments rarely factor in the *complete* cost of living difference (especially when you include things like commute time, size/quality/age of home, etc). You're likely coming out significantly better off than if you had moved.

Comment: I’m not going to downvote this but I do want to point out that it’s reasonable to believe one is compensated for the quality of one’s work and not for where one lives. I don’t think it’s fair or kind to say the asker "simply made too much" and "got away with it".

Comment: @user71659: A few caveats to that: 1) Locality adjustments are not based on cost-of-living, but on local employment costs; if the cost-of-living shoots up 50%, but jobs only pay 20% more, locality adjustments are balanced on the latter. 2) The locality adjustments fall behind because they never allocate enough to fully pay the adjustments for each locality; it costs a lot more than that to live in SF or Manhattan than "Podunk". 3) The percentages are meaningless without noting that "Rest of U.S." has an adjustment of 16.5%; Seattle is only 11.2% above Podunk, NYC is up 16.9%, SF is up 23.7%.

Comment: @ToddWilcox In the US, it's a huge political deal that "jobs go overseas" and "get the jobs back". Assuming that a job is paid by it's productive outcome and not by where you live is naive at best. Would it be great? Sure. But it's far from reality and that reality is not a hidden secret, it's even a talking point in presidential campaigns on national TV.

Comment: @ToddWilcox so why don't we pay Romanian subcontractors who do great work 150k$ ? Because they live in a place where everything (on average) is a LOT cheaper so even though they learn less on paper, the luxury they can enjoy with that salary (aka the experienced reward for that quality work) is the exact same as if they were paid a lot (on paper) in an expensive place.

Comment: "*I would not be surprised if you ended up with a net positive for not moving.*" I don't see how you could get that. You pay more for things, but that always means that the things you get are worth more. You would have to assume that he values things differently from how everyone else does to find that he gets a net positive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz value of money doesn't change no matter how you look at it, $1 is $1.

Comment: @Alvi15 Yes, and neither does the value of housing. $1 of rent gets $1 worth of housing. People pay more for rent in Seattle because the value of the housing is greater.

Comment: so why does it matter that he values things differently? Answerer were suggesting for OP to actually math out his income and expense difference on living in Seattle vs Midwest, and it's answerer opinion that he _may_ end up in net positive. Whether it actually the case or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @ToddWilcox for better or worse, I also work at a big tech company and this is explicitly not the case. Target compensation is derived from the distribution of total compensations for people in your role, where you live

Comment: @Alvi15 My point is that he probably doesn't value things differently from the way everyone else does and so wouldn't consider cheaper housing and more expensive housing equal in value. Comparing income and expense differences while not accounting for value differences doesn't make sense. People pay more to live in Seattle for a reason, a reason he will not get if he's in Seattle. He should not ignore that loss of value in his comparison.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if that's the case the question can never be answered properly because it heavily depends on subjective opinion, at least OP needs to be more clear about his priority.

Comment: @Alvi15 Well the simplest assumption to make is that he values things the same way everyone else does. He considers $1 of rent to buy him $1 worth of housing from which he derives $1 of benefit. Clearly, people prefer to live in Seattle to wherever he's living now because they're willing to pay more to do it. That preference has some value that he would get in Seattle but does not get where he is now.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz are you saying that a gallon of milk is _actually worth_ more than twice as much in Alaska than it is in Indiana because my son has to _pay more_ than twice as much as I do? Or, is it possibly simply because it costs more to produce/deliver said gallon to AK than IN. I've had his AK milk - it doesn't taste any better than IN milk...

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, I am saying a gallon of milk is actually worth more than twice as much in Alaska than it is in Indiana. And the proof is that if I owed you $1,000 and we agreed to payment in the form of gallons of milk, we would agree to very different numbers of gallons of milk in Alaska than we would in Indiana. The milk may not taste any better Alaska, but people are willing to pay twice as much to get that taste rather than move to Indiana for the cheaper milk because having milk in Alaska over Indiana has other valuable benefits to them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz or simply no one is willing to sell milk for half the existing price in Alaska, so only those willing to pay the extra amount buy milk there. Likely people in Indiana value milk the same, but more people buy it or they buy more because it's cheaper.

Comment: @Kat They buy it if they need it more. You're willing to use things you don't value too highly casually and frequently. But unless you're particularly wealthy, things you value more highly you can't use as often or as much of.

Comment: "Salary adjustments based on cost of living are very common." I'm assuming something has to be in the contract about it though?

Comment: @Mast at least for this question, seems like it would be there, since they're pretty explicit about it.

Comment: One other thing the OP can do is to have an estimate of the local pay for a similar technical role and compare it with 115K they are getting now. If 115K is still noticeably higher, then it indeed seems their team values them and pay for the quality work they produce.

Comment: @Alvi15: $1 is not $1 everywhere. The value of a dollar determines what and how much it can buy. That value is not the same in all locales.

Comment: @Mast: No, it doesn't need to be in the contract in most cases. Many states are "at will". The company can change the conditions of your employment at any time for any reason. If you disagree with those changes, you are free to quit. There are protected circumstances based on different legal jurisdictions, and for the most part the ultimate power lies in your ability to quit if you don't like your working conditions.

Answer (score 50):

I am a manager at a FAANG sized company in the Seattle area and had to steer an employee of mine through this when he moved out east at the start of the pandemic. It wasn't a fun thing to break the news to him about this either.

So yes, this is a legal and real thing to have a salary adjustment when an employee changes states or regions. Effectively, he had to sign another offer letter. He was effectively being offered a new job in a new state. There were other incentives to help offset the adjustment.

Something to know.  The salary adjustment is not based on the cost of living of your location (as others on this page have erroneously cited).  It is actually about getting paid the market rate for tech engineers in your region of the country.

That is, if you live in Nebraska, engineers probably don't make as much there as they would in San Francisco or Seattle. The company doesn't want to pay Seattle salaries if there is limited local competition for business that need your services. It just so happens, that cost-of-living is typically lower in these same regions. But that's not why the company is adjusting the rate. While companies are embracing remote workers, they are also taking advantage of it being less expensive for them.

As such, you likely have some sort of promotion or ladder level assigned to you (based on experience, past performance reviews, promotions, etc...).  And the company sets the salary for your role and there's a matrix for what that level pays in each region. It's not your manager's fault, it sounds like they've been diligently giving you raises and promotions during your tenure - hence, they value your work.

So start with this in considering what you are worth:

- What do other tech companies in your mid-west city pay for equivalent skills and experience?  Do they pay anywhere near the Seattle salary you had before?
- And would you be happier working there in your current city for a different company that might be slightly more, but not quite what the Seattle office pays?
- Consider the quality of life and cost of living in Seattle compared to your current location. It is indeed expensive to live in Seattle. Housing prices and rent have exploded in the past few years. Food and gas are expensive. And I've known several people who have visited and were aghast at the [homeless population downtown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homelessness_in_Seattle). You might find that $150K here doesn't go as far as $115K where you are currently at.

Now, how can you overcome the pain of your salary reduction?

- Periodically, in an appropriate way without whining, advocate for promotions and have career discussions with your manager. Advocate for yourself and ask what you need to do to get to the next promotion level sooner.  Express to your manager your disappointment with the pay hit you took. You need them to be your biggest advocate.
- Periodically scout out new employment in your area. Just having a profile in LinkedIn with the "Open To Finding a New Job" setting enable might get some recruiters contacting you. Do consider that a  base salary from a local company might be higher than your current salary, but it probably won't compete with your periodic bonus and stock awards you get now.
- Consider moving to Washington State, but not downtown Seattle. You might find that the company's definition of "eligible for Seattle pay" is really anywhere in the state, and not just Puget Sound. (I believe that's the case with my company).  Check with your HR department. Then consider if there's anywhere else around here that looks interesting.

You didn't say which company, but we might be co-workers. If you look me up and we work at the same place, feel free to hit me up for more insider tips.

Comment: The Seattle-based company is outsourcing a job so it makes sense that they'll pay less. It just so happens that they're outsourcing to Nebraska instead of India.

Comment: "The company doesn't want to pay Seattle salaries if the only competition for your services is with a farming company that occasionally needs a sys-admin who can program some of the time. It just so happens, that cost-of-living is typically lower in these same regions. But that's not why the company is adjusting the rate. While companies are embracing remote workers, they are also taking advantage of it being less expensive for them."  This doesn't really make sense, if we're considering remote work that's effective, they complete with the whole time zone (whole world for flexible people)

Comment: "It is actually about getting paid the market rate" -> So it's the snake biting its own tail as we say in my country, workers are paid the market rate, and the market rate is such because you workers get paid this amount, because that's the market rate.. how do we get out the vicious cricle?

Comment: @Kaddath Supply and demand. If there's fewer available workers willing to be paid current market rate, market rate goes up. If there's more workers than jobs, market rate goes down. -- This is why market rate in Seattle is higher. Companies would prefer to pay Peoria wages to Seattle residents, but if they did, workers would look at the cost of living, laugh, and either find a better paying job or leave for Peoria. You couldn't fill Seattle jobs until wages go up (or until companies are willing to go remote and hire from Peoria).

Comment: I upvoted your answer in general, however regarding this `if the only competition for your services is with a farming company that occasionally needs a sys-admin who can program`, those sysadmins would never pass the interview at FANG. What if you are the only developer in a remote Alaskan town? Should they suddenly pay you minimum wage? Companies will offer/pay you less if they can afford to lose you. It's game of risk, which 2022 proved big tech is losing.

Comment: "**You didn't say which company, but we might be co-workers**". You may just be his manager. :-)

Comment: @Kaddath The vicious circle is broken when people like OP say "Okay, if you won't pay me what we agreed, then I will not work here. This is constructive dismissal." ("agreement" and "constructive dismissal" might or might not fly in a courtroom, but it's not a courtroom) Then the company keeps being unable to find workers because they all quit when they learn about this arrangement, so it stops doing this arrangement.

Comment: Re "getting paid the market rate for tech engineers in your region of the country": Since Covid has shown that remote work in IT is a thing (and it obviously is for the OP's employer and their employees): The market rate has just become very flat. (This may be bad news for tech guys in SF and very good news in Nebraska, and Hyderabad.) If the employee doesn't like the money they can look elsewhere, and vice versa. I'd never have agreed to this reduction.

Comment: Just out of interest: are you known as "selbie" in your company?

Comment: I wonder what makes this legal? Did the contract say anything about where the employee has to live?

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, after reading and re-reading the question here and some of the responses to this, I feel like one very large angle is being overlooked in the morass of legality, ethics and at-will employment.

> [My salary being reduced from ~$150K to $115K is] very depressing because I feel like I am not being valued but my manager and my teammates have been happy with my work. I even got a salary increase a few months ago.

You were tying the value you bring to the company directly with your salary. This...is a convenient way to do it, but is almost always an incomplete figure.

It has already been well-established in other answers that yes, this is perfectly legal and yes, this is perfectly allowed, and yes this is entirely on-pace with the nature of remote vs office work, in that the company is allowed to compromise with the desires of the employee and the need for them to fill the office space.

What you're not factoring in is the projected value and worth you're bringing to the company, which is resultant of a salary adjustment because of your ZIP code.

What I would encourage is a discussion with your manager about this.  Be frank and open, but don't whine if you can help it.

- State your perspective on the matter.  If you wish to continue working there, express that clearly.  If you are thinking of looking around, **do not *lead* with that** since that will make you a flight risk to the company.
- Express your opinion on the value that you bring to the company.  Cite recent projects, colleague accolades, and things that you have had a direct hand in improving around the place.
- Ask your manager if there's something there that can help reinforce the value you bring to the place, as the recent salary adjustment put the story in your head that you were less valued than before.

Having open and frank discussions like this with your management will help you charter next steps. It could be a title change for you; it could be a new job for you.  Don't wallow in indecisiveness on talking with people about this, and don't let the salary adjustment that is orthogonal to your performance tell you that you are less than adequate at your job.

Comment: It's indeed the most confusing point about the whole question, why is OP _solely_ tying their salary cut to the their performance? They were told otherwise too.

Comment: @Alvi15 That's what happens when someone just cannot grasp the concept that their salary might be tied to something other than their performance. It's like being unable to explain to someone that you chose a lower paying job because the higher paying job makes your life miserable.

Comment: @DKNguyen it's kind of different because of my experience myself but I get your point.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things to consider from the employer's perspective.

1. The pandemic has upended working practices, but many policies were written before the pandemic, and at least some businesses probably still hope to at some point return to pre-pandemic normal.
2. There are advantages to having an employee be local, even if they are not coming in to the office every day. Tools like zoom and teams are often a poor substitute for getting a bunch of people in a room together to thrash something out. Or when someone needs a peice of equipment they can just collect it rather than having to arrange shipping.
3. If you want to hire people in a high wage area, or convince people to move to a high cost of living area you will have to pay them more than you would for people of similar skill level in a lower wage, lower cost of living area.

Answer (score 4):

If the employment contract or the job offer explicitly states that your salary is 150k with the condition that you move to Seattle, then **unfortunately**, the company can try to use that as an argument to reduce your salary.

Some companies allow employees to work remotely during the time of COVID. But, now, things have improved, and they want workers to go back to the offices.

---

If you want to stay in the mid-west and work for this company, maybe you still can negotiate with them by saying that the salary reduction of $35K is too much. Maybe, you can try to ask them to reduce less than $35K.

---

However, if the company's job offer does not say anything about your moving to Seattle as a requirement to get the salary of $150K, then you can talk to an employment lawyer.

Comment: yeah, I'm afraid that somewhere in OP's salary breakdown, the company listed $35k as a reimbursement for living near the office.

Comment: Cost-of-living adjustments to salary are common. It would have been appropriate for the company to state this clearly as part of the offer and contract... and they may have done so.

Comment: @Alvi15, I also guess somehow the job offer may very well say that the salary they offered him is based on his moving to Seattle.

Comment: @keshlam - believe it or not, **it's not a cost of living adjustment per-se**. It's the company paying the **market rate** for engineers in that region of the country.

Comment: I think that's a matter of how the company decides the amount and manages it's bookkeeping and describes it to the employee more than anything else, @selbie... it comes out to essentially the same thing once that justification and cakculation has been done. Unless there are tax implications I'm not aware of...?

Comment: @selbie, I think you and user keshlam are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 - I think it would be interesting see what FAANG companies that do pay adjustments would do for someone wanting to work remote from Hawaii.  A state that has the highest cost of living, but not necessarily a high demand for engineering talent.

Comment: If the company wants people to work from/in Hawaii, they will pay what's needed to get them there. If they employee wants to work from Hawaii and it isn't advantageous to the company -- never mind possibly being disadvantageous -- I can't blame the company for declining to pay more; that's the employee's lifestyle choice and they need to decide whether it's worth the higher cost. It's the same as the living-in-NYC question; if the company needs you there I'd expect them to make it reasonably affordable, if they don't you do it on your own budget.

Answer (score 4):

Unless its written in the contract and you signed it, I would never accept this. I expect my salary to reflect the values I create - not the cost of my living. With "cost of living logic" a company should pay me a higher salary just because I got a new and more expensive car or bought a huge mansion. Thats not how it is, so it should be the same when you have reduced your cost of living.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question or whether it's normal or allowed. Nor does it give any useful practical advice as to how to address the situation. If it's normal and allowed, then taking a moral stance doesn't mean much. And if it's abnormal, it needs some advice on how to negotiate with the employer.

Comment: The examples are not comparable. You being in Seattle gives value to the company, so they pay you for that. The company does not get any value from you buying an expensive car, so they do not pay for that.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect a raise if you HAD TO live in NYC, San Francisco or Seattle?

Answer (score 2):

> is this normal or even allowed?

Yes it is normal. Very few workers in the United States have contracts that specify these things in detail. It is not unusual to hear of salary cuts. It happens when business slows or company income doesn't support the current pay scales.

If it is allowed, depends on the Labor laws in your state. In general at-will employment laws give your employer options:

- they can tell you no move or be let go;
- they can cut your pay, or
- they can decide to allow you to work remote at your current pay.

They are expecting that you will either move to Washington state, or they will fill your slot with somebody who will.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of US Employment Law (I am neither a lawyer nor an American) is that, in at-will employment, the employer is heavily favoured in almost everything.  Can they cut your salary?  Sure.  For any reason (unless it's directly protected by the constitution, e.g. discrimination, or by your employment contract), by any  amount.  They can even cut it all the way down to zero, by terminating you without cause without delay (your boss can pull you into a meeting, say "you're fired", and that's all there is to it).

Is it legal?  Sure.  Is it normal?  Well, consider that companies like to have people working for them, and they like to have skilled people working for them more.  If the company wants to retain skilled talent, then it's not normal; if you are providing value, then they should appreciate your performance and pay you more (or at least not cut your salary by paying you less).  Meaning, either you are not performing as well as you think you are, or your company does not appreciate you.

"Cost-of-living" is a red herring, as far as I'm concerned.  The company may say they see it otherwise, but they don't.  You "can" live on less money in Podunk than in Seattle, that's true.  The company also "can" afford to pay you a Seattle salary even if you're living in Podunk, because they're a reputable and stand-up company who treats their employees well; the fact that you're living in Podunk doesn't suddenly impact the company's finances such that they have to cut your salary by 25% because they can't afford the Seattle salary.

Given that you mentioned that you are working for FAANG (which is only 5 companies, by definition) and that their office is in Seattle, I have a feeling I know which company this is.  As an ex-Brazilian myself (by employment history, not geneology), I will tell you this is not a stand-up or reputable company, in this or any other way.  If you're making 25% less of your salary, you should work 25% less and spend that 25% of your time finding another job.

Comment: "Cost of living" does factor in quite heavily to working agreements.  As in, if you're expected to work remote or something along those lines, then you can be paid according to their schedule for a remote employee. Companies, to your point, want to have people work for them, and with the pandemic really wrecking work-in-office settings, the compromise that employers make is that you can live where you want, but the pay needs to be adjusted to suit what is fair market value in your town (e.g. if a FAANG were in Podunk).

Comment: Encouraging someone to "work less" is usually also not going to bode well; the company is still at-will so they could decide that they really wanted that 25% of effort from you and they're not getting it, so then you get no salary and have no job.  Lose-lose for everyone.

Comment: @Makoto The thing about employment agreements is that you are paid what you are worth, full stop.  If you are paid $150k, then you are worth $150k.  If you are paid $115k, then you are worth $115k.  If you live in Seattle, or you live in Podunk, that doesn't (or, shouldn't) change how much you are worth, because the effort you do, the responsibilities you have, and the output of your work is the same.  If the company believes that your locale makes you worth more or less, then they don't value your work and they think you are replaceable.  So let them replace you; find somewhere you're valued.

Comment: Great theory, @Ertai87. How happy would you be if the reverse happened, the company moved your job to a high cost-of-living location and didn't agree to increase your salary so you don't suffer a real quality -of-living decrease? You can't expect the positive adjustment without the negative one. You can certainly attempt to negotiate this, or quit because you think you're being dissed, but from the company's point of view those are two sides of the same coin; it may not be what you would prefer but it isn't unfair.

Comment: @keshlam That's not even the real consideration of that situation.  The consideration is that keeping my job would require me to move.  Given that OP works in a FAANG, the company will have to justify (in court of law, because I will sue them, if I have no other choice) why I have to move, given that the company supports remote work and has for the last 3 years.  But even if they can, such is not particularly unusual; FAANG companies do often pay, in their locales, far below cost-of-living.

Comment: (Source: I know multiple people who work for FAANGs who have to have roommates because they can't afford rent in their locale in any other way)

Comment: The other thing, though, is, that if I'm not making enough money in my current locale to afford cost-of-living in the new locale, perhaps the company doesn't value my work that much after all and I should find another job where I'm more valued.  Also, quality-of-living is relative and considers many factors, not all monetary.  For example, if you live in a place where there is lots of stuff to do, you have many friends, and you speak the local language, and you move to a place where none of those are true, I would argue that's a QOL decrease that has nothing to do with money.

Comment: Uhm.... From the description, it sounded like the choice being discussed her was move it be paid less, not move or lose job or be underpaid relative to local rates in area of residence. Not saying that isn't an issue, or that demands to relocate haven't sometimes amounted to "constructive firing", just that unless I missed something that seems like a different question.

Comment: And yeah, if the company isn't paying you an acceptable wage, however you define that, of course you should be interviewing elsewhere. Again, different question than "should I get the same wage working from one location as from another". And I'm not even saying that shouldn't be true, only that it's a double edged sword and there will be someone hurt no matter which way it swings. Life's like that.

Comment: That's what you suggested though.  You said that if you don't accept being paid less in a place with a lower COL, then you should accept not being paid more in a place with a higher COL.  To which I agree.  My statement on that simply is that a job is worth what the job is worth.  If you're making less than you want (for any reason), it's because your company (rightly or wrongly) doesn't value you enough to pay you what you want to be paid.  So, improve your value (work harder/better), or find another job that values you more.

Comment: Also, as I said, I've worked for this company before, and I will tell you that HR at this company does not do anything "by accident", and they do lie, a lot, about why they take punitive action against their employees.  Given the company that this is, I wouldn't put it past them for this to be a form of "constructive firing"; they definitely engage in such a practice and did so to me while I worked for them (not to an extent that I think I could win in court, but it definitely happened).

Comment: @Makoto Cost-of-living factors into work agreements to the extent that companies pay you the least they feel they can get away with, and they feel they can get away with less if you live in a LCOL area. It's not a direct factor, and there's no reason it has to be this way. An employee can equally well say to the employer, that it is the employee's choice how to spend his own money, and if he chooses to spend less on living and more on new TVs for example, that is not something the employer can discriminate against.

Comment: @Makoto Consider the actual opposite: if the employee chooses to live in a penthouse apartment in downtown Manhattan, should the employer pay them enough for their new lifestyle? Or is the extra cost the employee's problem? If the extra cost from living in a HCOL area is the employee's problem, then the reduced cost from living in an LCOL area should also be the employee's benefit. The employer shouldn't be able to have their cake and eat it. The fact they *can* have their cake and eat it, is a symptom of how messed up the economic/financial system is, not some moral principle.

Answer (score -4):

Looking at the troubles that FAANG companies are facing recently (lower stock valuations due to higher risk-free rates, degradation of the profitability and other downgrades), they have to reduce their costs. However, it is not a good idea to tell openly to the public (stock owners) that the internal situation deteriorated, thus, they have to use indirect methods to reduce costs. One such a method is described very well in your post.

And, as someone pointed out, this is completely legal in US, but probably harder to achieve in Europe.

Comment: Not my DV, but I doubt that FAANG companies reduce costs on a "lets see what we can find for this specific person" level.

Comment: That's good news. But I would not be surprised, if this were not the case.